# Terraform & GCP: Google kubernetes cluster problem: Can't see monitoring section (memory and cpu) inside workloads (deployments, statefulsets)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I spent 4 days already testing all configurations from kubernetes terraform gcp module and I can't see the metrics of my workloads, It never shows me CPU nor Memory (and even the standard default created kubernetes in the GUI has this activated.

Here's my code:

```
resource "google_container_cluster" "default" {
  provider = google-beta
  name        = var.name
  project     = var.project_id
  description = "Vectux GKE Cluster"
  location    = var.zonal_region
  remove_default_node_pool = true
  initial_node_count       = var.gke_num_nodes
  master_auth {
    #username = ""
    #password = ""
    client_certificate_config {
      issue_client_certificate = false
    }
  }
  timeouts {
    create = "30m"
    update = "40m"
  }
  logging_config {
    enable_components = ["SYSTEM_COMPONENTS", "WORKLOADS"]
  }
  monitoring_config {
    enable_components = ["SYSTEM_COMPONENTS", "WORKLOADS"]
  }
}

resource "google_container_node_pool" "default" {
  name       = "${var.name}-node-pool"
  project    = var.project_id
  location   = var.zonal_region
  node_locations = [var.zonal_region]
  cluster    = google_container_cluster.default.name
  node_count = var.gke_num_nodes
 
  node_config {
    preemptible  = true
    machine_type = var.machine_type
    disk_size_gb = var.disk_size_gb
    service_account = google_service_account.default3.email
    oauth_scopes = [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
      "compute-ro",
      "storage-ro",
      "service-management",
      "service-control",
    ]
    metadata = {
      disable-legacy-endpoints = "true"
    }
  }

  management {
    auto_repair  = true
    auto_upgrade = true
  }
}


resource "google_service_account" "default3" {
  project      = var.project_id
  account_id   = "terraform-vectux-33"
  display_name = "tfvectux2"
  provider     = google-beta
}
```

Here's some info on the cluster (when I compare against the standard one with the metrics enabled I see no differences: [image]

And here 's the workload view without the metrics that I'd like to see:
[image]

Comment: What Terraform version and what provider registry version for google-beta are you using? Is this your full code? I've replicated this (created GKE cluster normally and your terraform script) and creating using UI shown workloads and form your code didn't. However I've created another cluster using UI with your `Service Account` and I cannot get any workload metrics. Did you try to add [IAM policy for service account](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/google_service_account_iam) to provide for example default `Compute Engine` permissions?

Comment: I tried your code without using that SA so I guess thats the root cause. Do you need this specific Service account? You cannot use default one for this scenario?

Comment: great for checking and let me know how it worked for you @PjoterS. I believe then that you are right. I can use some other service account, yes. I just wanted to also deploy a new service account in the same terraform project. I thought the oauth thing would help with that but maybe I'm missing some scopes or something. I'll do some testings in my end using a service account with all accesses and hopefully I'll be able to see the metrics. Again thanks for checking and I'll come back asap to say if it worked.

Comment: To make it work you would need to use `google_project_iam_binding` with `role/owner` or 2 roles: `"roles/compute.admin` and `"roles/logging.logWriter"`. I will do some additional tests and will post detailed answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment to solve your issue, you must add `google_service_account_iam_binding` module and grant your `Service Account` specific role - `roles/monitoring.metricWriter`. In comments I mention that you can also grant `role/compute.admin` but after another test I've run it's not necessary.

Below is a terraform snippet I've used to create a test cluster with `Service Account` called `sa`. I've changed some fields in `node config`. In your case, you would need to add the whole `google_project_iam_binding` module.

**Terraform Snippet**

```
### Creating Service Account
resource "google_service_account" "sa" {
  project      = "my-project-name"
  account_id   = "terraform-vectux-2"
  display_name = "tfvectux2"
  provider     = google-beta
}
### Binding Service Account with IAM
resource "google_project_iam_binding" "sa_binding_writer" {
  project = "my-project-name"
  role    = "roles/monitoring.metricWriter"
  members = [
    "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.sa.email}" 
    ### in your case it will be "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.your-serviceaccount-name.email}"
  ]
}

resource "google_container_cluster" "default" {
  provider = google-beta
  name        = "cluster-test-custom-sa"
  project     = "my-project-name"
  description = "Vectux GKE Cluster"
  location    = "europe-west2"
  remove_default_node_pool = true
  initial_node_count       = "1"
  master_auth {
    #username = ""
    #password = ""
    client_certificate_config {
      issue_client_certificate = false
    }
  }
  timeouts {
    create = "30m"
    update = "40m"
  }
  logging_config {
    enable_components = ["SYSTEM_COMPONENTS", "WORKLOADS"]
  }
  monitoring_config {
    enable_components = ["SYSTEM_COMPONENTS", "WORKLOADS"]
  }
}

resource "google_container_node_pool" "default" {
  name       = "test-node-pool"
  project    = "my-project-name"
  location   = "europe-west2"
  node_locations = ["europe-west2-a"]
  cluster    = google_container_cluster.default.name
  node_count = "1"

  node_config {
    preemptible  = "true"
    machine_type = "e2-medium"
    disk_size_gb = 50
    service_account = google_service_account.sa.email
    ###service_account = google_service_account.your-serviceaccount-name.email
    oauth_scopes = [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
      "compute-ro",
      "storage-ro",
      "service-management",
      "service-control",
    ]
    metadata = {
      disable-legacy-endpoints = "true"
    }
  }

  management {
    auto_repair  = true
    auto_upgrade = true
  }
}
```

**My Screens:**

**Whole workload**
[image]

**Node Workload**
[image]

**Additional Information**

If you would add just `roles/compute.admin` you might see workload for the whole application,but you wouldn't be able to see each node workload. With `"roles/monitoring.metricWriter"` you are able to see the whole application workload and each node workload. To achieve what you want - see workloads in the node, you just need `"roles/monitoring.metricWriter"`.

You need to use `"google_project_iam_binding"` as without this in IAM roles, you won't have your newly created `Service Account` and it will lack permission. In short, Your new SA will be visible in `IAM & Admin > Service Accounts` but there will be no entry in `IAM & Admin > IAM`.

If you want more information about IAM and Binding in terraform, please check [this Terraform Documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/google_service_account_iam)

As a last thing, please remember that [Oauth Scope](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/container_cluster#oauth_scopes) with `"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"` gives access to all GCP resources.

Comment: yes @WytrzymałyWiktor, accepted as an answer already and appreciate a lot the answer, thanks again PjoterS